# Hover image, haven't touch the image but it works, how to remove extra hidden image?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I've tried many ways for almost 2 days but seems like I hit the wall. Have a look at the picture. I hover a little bit on the corner, but it's working although I haven't touch the images yet. I want to remove extra image. (Clearly, I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> on the website to see the image to make sure there are no extras because I want to make hover).

[image]

Here is my code for body

```
<div id="social">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> <img src="facebook.png"> </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <img src="twitter.png"> </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <img src="youtube.png"> </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <img src="tumblr.png"> </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <img src="spotify.png"> </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and for my css..

```
#social {
    margin-top:20px;
}

#social ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#social ul li a {
    margin-right:10px;
}

#social ul li a img {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    filter:grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* For Webkit browsers */
    filter: gray; /* For IE 6 - 9 */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
}

#social ul li a:hover img {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

So far, I thought this problem maybe rely on padding and margin and I tried to make padding 0 and margin 0, but it's still not working. Or the problem with .png format? I'm so confused, really!! Does any of you have solution? Thanks.

Here is my JSfiddle so that you guys are able to understand : http://jsfiddle.net/MkNm2/

Comment: Upload your image, at tinypic or imageshack and use the direct link for your fiddle in order to work. :)

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/84EL3/1/

Comment: The image is a PNG and thus rectangular. Thus the hover will apply regardless of whether the hovered part is transparent or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm so confused, so means there are no solutions for this?

Comment: Nope. not really. You could use an SVG element instead of an image but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: Frankly, it's not worth worrying about a couple of pixels here and there. I'd leave it and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is a `png` you are hovering on the transparent part and so this happens. There is no solution to avoid this up to my knowledge.

Comment: So what suggestion you can ask me to do? I tried to change jpg, but it's still the same because I'm using border-radius.

Comment: Not much you can do AFAIK...all elements are rectangular.